# JSON Error in Python 3.5

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read a JSON file, but I am getting an error. I am not sure how to solve this.

```
import json

data = json.load(open('nutrients.json'))
```

The Errors message

```
runfile('D:/Quant/MSQF/6 - Programming in Python II/3 - Data
Analysis/Project 3.py', wdir='D:/Quant/MSQF/6 - Programming in Python
II/3 - Data Analysis') Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-2d9c14f60649>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Quant/MSQF/6 - Programming in Python II/3 - Data Analysis/Project 3.py', wdir='D:/Quant/MSQF/6 - Programming in Python
II/3 - Data Analysis')

  File
"D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File
"D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Quant/MSQF/6 - Programming in Python II/3 - Data
Analysis/Project 3.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = json.load(open('nutrients.json'))

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\json\__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

JSONDecodeError: Extra data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely what you have there isn't a JSON file, it's a JSONL (JSON lines) file.

That means there are several JSON objects in the file, and you can read them all using:

```
import json

with open("nutrients.json") as f:
    objects = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
```

If this doesn't work then the format differs from this pseudo-standard, and you'd have to look into the file to see what's wrong.